# What would happen if I were to shine light on a metal for a long time?

Tags: photons, experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect, ionization-energy

According to photoelectric effect, shining light of sufficient energy would ionized an electron from a metal.
So what would happen if I were to shine a light on the metal for a very long time?
Will the metal become unstable at some time in future due to the excess build up of positive charge in the metal?

Also, does anyone know if any such experiment has been conducted?

Answer (score 3):

If the metal were not grounded then there would indeed be a build up of positive charge on the surface of the metal. As a result of the electron depletion, the work function of the material would increase and, if the same frequency of light were used for long times, the metal would eventually cease to emit electrons and reach equilibrium. This can be understood similarly to the process of charging a capacitor - it becomes harder (requires more energy) to remove electrons from the metal plate over time as we must also overcome the Columbic attraction.

Comment: Note that the “work function” is a surface effect, independent of the electric potential of the metal. While it is correct that a positively-charged conductor will emit fewer photoelectrons at a given illumination than a positively-charged conductor, it’s not quite right to think of this as an “increase of the work function.”